# Can't access to array of characters (string) inside a structure

Tags: c

Thank you in advance, I'm new at C programming so I'll explain my problem as well as I can. I can't access to any element in array of characters of a struct I get "segmentation fault", the struct is implemented as a stack.

```
 typedef struct Nodo
 {
  int valor;
  char nombre[50];
 }Nodo;
 
 void push(Nodo** p, int v, char nom[])/*char aut,char gen,int valo*/
 {
   Nodo *nuevo = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
   nuevo->valor=v;
   nuevo->nombre[50];
   nuevo->sig=*p;
   *p=nuevo;
 }
  
 void getliner(char* nom[50])
 {
   printf("Escriba el nombre de la canción\n");
   fgets(nom, 50, stdin);
   nom[strlen(nom) -1] = '\0';
   printf("The user has entered %s\n",nom);
 }

 void clear(void)
 {
   while ( getchar() != '\n' );
 }

 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
 {
   int i = 0;
   char nom[50];
   Nodo* p = NULL;

   printf("Agregar texto\n");

   getliner(&nom);
   for(int i = 0;nom[i]=='\0';i++)
   {
     p->nombre[i]=nom[i];
   }
   printf("%c\n",p->nombre[0]);
  {
```

Comment: What is this line  in push for? `nuevo->nombre[50];`

Comment: Presumably in `push()` you need `strcpy(nuevo->nombre, nom);` to copy the parameter into the structure.  You might want to check that the length of `nom` is less than the size of `nuevo->nombre` too.  Then you have to decide what to do if it _is_ too long.

Comment: Is `getliner()` really supposed to take an array of char *pointers*?

Comment: `p` is NULL, so attempting to write to `p->nombre[i]` is undefined behavior. A common way undefined behavior manifests (especially when trying to access a NULL pointer) is with a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

In `main` you have:

```
Nodo *p = NULL;
...
for ( ... ) {
    p->nombre[i]=nom[i];
}
```

So `p` is `NULL`, it does not point to anything. So the resulting segmentation fault is unsurprising.

Allocate memory with malloc, or do not use a pointer.